Why does Apple add a key for §
I always wondered why does Apple include a key for § in all their keyboards for my country of Portugal.
The same applies to the shift character ±.
It doesn't seem to have any use within macOS, although I use it to create special keyboard shortcuts, since no software seems to make use of it.
I understand not all hardware has this key layout, but it is prominent here, on the top left of the keyboard, before the key 1.
Like this:

I'm from Portugal and all keyboards here have this key. I don't work in the legal system but I have never seen a legal document with this symbol.
It seems to be used by other EU countries and probably added to the Portuguese keyboards by association.
Is there a reason Apple includes this key that’s related to a software feature?

I don't have this key on any of the Apple (and non-Apple) keyboards here in the US. Where are you located on this small planet?

@IconDaemon The Swiss keyboard has § to the left of 1.

§ is quite commonly used in Germany and other countries. ± is quite common if you do a bit of maths. And my two good friends Zoë and Chloë are quite happy that Apple isn't naïve and lets them type their names without problems.

Well, I've never been to Switzerland, but I'd like to go sometime!

@IconDaemon You are welcome :-) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tastaturbelegung#Schweiz, so most likely Apple just adapts the standard keyboard of the country. OTOH none of the german ones seems to have ±.

PS: I reopened the question, think this can be answered without guessing Apple's intentions.

@IconDaemon US keyboards have § on option 6 and ± on option shift =

But that's an option keypress, not a printed symbol on an actual key, which is what I assume the OP is describing.

For the use of § and where it can be found on various keyboards, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

@IconDaemon - the US ANSI keyboard has one key missing entirely, so and ~ go left of 1. The ISO keyboard used by much of the rest ot the world gains a key left of Z, which for the UK is where and ~ are placed. Other languages often have something other there. This can leave a 'spare' key left of 1, which gets filled in a myriad different ways - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout

I’m voting to close this question because "why Apple does something" is generally unknown.

The silcrow § and pilcrow ¶ are important typographic elements for legal writing. Why they are included in computer layouts for certain countries are banal and likely totally unrelated to Apple decisions at all since key layouts are often common to many vendors of computer hardware and not just uniquely macOS and Apple keyboard decisions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silcrow
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus%E2%80%93minus_sign

A little research in general drives an easy conclusion that the use of many keys on macOS is clearly to generate a symbol that some portion of the population uses regularly.
Another easy conclusion is that different regions prioritize different character sets and that within those regions, a standard layout is highly beneficial and traditional but not always achieved across all keys and keyboard visual and physical layouts.
For your specific region and this specific section character, it could easily be ranked more common for legal use and that subset of the population has enough representation and/or influence for those two punctuation being most important over other alternatives.

There even might be legal requirements, or unions, demanding specific keyboard layouts (e.g. in Germany).

Who better than the legislature to write a law that makes their jobs easier, @nohillside

The Portuguese keyboard standard has it at AltGr+4. Apple have indeed made a decision to ignore the standard and use a dedicated key for it.

Thanks @OrangeDog - AltGr + 4 appears to be the mapping for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCESAR keyboards as well.

The whole point of this answer (it's because of regions and standards shared between vendors, not at all because of Apple) seems to be contradicted by the fact that Apple does not follow the standard or the layout of other vendors, but added a dedicated key for this. Even the point of the great importance in legal writing seems to be contradicted by the OP's observations about Portuguese legal documents.
